# How to store all arrays in a for loop output

Tags: python, for-loop, storage

When I make this for loop, I only get one array printed out from the code

```
 npoints=10

x0 = np.zeros(npoints)
y0 = np.zeros(npoints)
z0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vx0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vy0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vz0 = np.zeros(npoints)
result=[]
#Set the initial conditions
for step in range(0,len(n1)):
     x0[0] = x1[step]
     y0[0] = y1[step]
     z0[0] = z1[step]

     vx0[0] = vx1[step]
     vy0[0] = vy1[step]
     vy0[0] = vz1[step]



print x0
```

This prints out the result

```
[-2.72482266  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
```

However, the output I *want* is what I get when I include the "print x0" inside of the loop. Like:

```
npoints=10

x0 = np.zeros(npoints)
y0 = np.zeros(npoints)
z0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vx0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vy0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vz0 = np.zeros(npoints)
result=[]
#Set the initial conditions
for step in range(0,len(n1)):
     x0[0] = x1[step]
     y0[0] = y1[step]
     z0[0] = z1[step]

     vx0[0] = vx1[step]
     vy0[0] = vy1[step]
     vy0[0] = vz1[step]



    print x0
```

and where my result is the desired:

```
[-0.29914467  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
[2.24151163 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
[-0.01034917  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]......
[-2.72482266  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
```

How could I store all of these arrays and not just the last one without printing in the for-loop??

Comment: You haven’t posted all your code—but is `xs=[]; …; xs.append(x0.copy())` all you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to create a 2D array for x0 to store all the recursive values like this

```
npoints=10

x0 = np.zeros([len(n1), npoints])
y0 = np.zeros(npoints)
z0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vx0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vy0 = np.zeros(npoints)
vz0 = np.zeros(npoints)
result=[]
#Set the initial conditions
for step in range(0,len(n1)):
    x0[step, 0] = x1[step]
    y0[0] = y1[step]
    z0[0] = z1[step]

    vx0[0] = vx1[step]
    vy0[0] = vy1[step]
    vy0[0] = vz1[step]



print x0
```

Comment: you can accept it as an answer by clicking the the right sign :)